# Set BOOL property from another class

Tags: objective-c, boolean

May I know how do I share a BOOL variable from one class to another class?

Here's what I am trying to do. I am setting the BOOL variable of FirstVC at SecondVC. What am I doing wrong here as the app crashes when I tried to change the BOOL value. With no error log.

FirstVC.h

```
@interface FirstVC : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
    BOOL pickUpAddressIsSet;

}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL pickUpAddressIsSet;
@end
```

FirstVC.m

```
@synthesize pickUpAddressIsSet;
```

secondVC.m

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
FirstVC *firstVC = (FirstVC *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];
firstVC.pickUpAddressIsSet = YES; // tried TRUE & 1
```

Comment: Are you sure there are at least two elements on your navigation stack? You may be indexing out of bounds into your array

Comment: @Perception Yes. I am able to set one of my NSString variable using firstVC object. SecondVC is pushed right on top of FirstVC which is the rootVC.

Comment: Please post the exact declaration of your *pickUpAddressIsSet* ivar and property from your .h file.

Comment: @Perception Have had my question edited.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Try doing *firstVC.pickupAddressIsSet = TRUE* and report back error, if any

Comment: Tried, crashes with no error too.

Comment: I found out that it's because I am trying to NSlog the BOOL variable as a string at other parts of the code.

Comment: Glad you found the problem, you may want to close your question or post a self-answer below. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign, getter= isPickUpAddressIsSet) BOOL pickUpAddressIsSet;
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `firstVC` instance isn't actually of the type (class) `FirstVC`, that would explain the error.

Try the following:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
id firstVC = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];
NSLog(@"%@", [firstVC class]);
```

What kind of class do you see in the NSLog output?

Comment: NSLog outputs as FirstVC. The assume the object is correct as I am able to set one of the NSString?

Answer (score 0):

```
firstVC.pickUpAddressIsSet: = YES;
```

Should be

```
firstVC.pickUpAddressIsSet = YES;
```

The colon should not be there.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo error. I have tried `firstVC.pickUpAddressIsSet = YES/TRUE/1` & `[firstVC setPickUpAddressIsSet:YES]` all doesn't seems to work...

Comment: In that case, I agree with everyone else in that your code looks fine. Which means the problem is in some part that we can't see. What happens if you try [firstVC respondsToSelector:@selector(setPickUpAddressIsSet)];

Comment: Also, set a breakpoint and step through the code, crashing without any error seems odd, you may get more information this way.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's because I am trying to NSlog the BOOL variable as a string at other parts of the code.